# SQL performance difference JOIN vs UNIONALL

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, join, union

I'm trying to improve a SQL query of mine, where I have to join two tables Post & PostItems. I've been able to figure out that the problem was caused due to an OR clause in my JOIN statement. My original query looks like this:

```
SELECT P.ID, IT.Total
FROM Post P
JOIN PostItem IT ON IT.PostID = P.ReferencePostID OR IT.PostID = P.ID
```

It takes this query about 6 minutes to spit out about 5k lines. If I split this query up like so:

```
SELECT P.ID, IT.Total
FROM Post P
JOIN PostItem IT ON P.ID = IT.PostID
                    
UNION ALL
                    
SELECT P.ID, IT.Total
FROM Post P 
JOIN PostItem IT ON P.ReferencePostID = IT.PostID
```

It'll spit out the exact same result, but it'll take less than a second. Any idea how this occurs?

For some more context, ID is the primary key of the Post table. PostID is a foreign key to ID. ReferencePostID has no constraint whatsoever.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Generate the execution plans for both statements and compare them.  You'll likely find that the first parses the tables just once, using one index, and uses HASH or NESTED LOOP joins, where the second parses the table twice, using different indexes each time, and uses a MERGE join.  *(Use the following site to share the plans if you want us to explain them to you, just edit your question to add the links to the plans... https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ )*

Comment: Or the data was cached in the buffer pool on the second run. consider SET STATISTICS IO ON to debug both queries

Comment: Different queries. How sure are you their results will always be the same?